# how to browse a map using the for loop

Tags: java

I got a map from my database, this map is as follows:

```
{70007564=[PensionMediumView : {mtBrutPension=10480.32, quartierId=LS, typePensionId=21, destinataireBulletin=1, txPensionRetenu=40.5,}]}
```

I try to display an error message if I find that the "typePensionId=21" (key number 3) by loop for.
I used the following code:

```
final Long idBeneficiaire = context.getIdPersonne();
        final Map<Long, List<PensionMediumView>> mapPensionsBeneficiaire = this.pensionBusinessApplicatif
            .recupererPensionsActivesParBeneficiaires(Arrays.asList(idBeneficiaire), context.getIdentificationContext());
    for (final Map.Entry<Long, List<PensionMediumView>> entry : mapPensionsBeneficiaire.entrySet()){
......
}
```

how can i display an error message if i find that "typePensionId=21"

Comment: "how to..." is very vague, please clarify what your issue is.

Comment: i change my question

Comment: Try `for(...) { if (...) { ... ; break; } }`...

Comment: I want to display a message (system.out.println ("error") when I find that the typepensioid = 21

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map) will help.

Comment: I think you will find an answer here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map)

Comment: You need a nested for loop to iterate map and every `List<PensionMediumView>`

Comment: It is json,i guess

Comment: Yes, is Json Type

Comment: @sami Check out my answer below, let me know if it clears things up for you. If it does, don't hesitate to accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe from your question that this is the sort of thing you're looking for. As i commented by the `if` statement, i wasn't sure exactly how to get the pension type id from looking at your example. Hopefully this helps.

```java
final Long idBeneficiaire = context.getIdPersonne();
final Map<Long, List<PensionMediumView>> mapPensionsBeneficiaire = this.pensionBusinessApplicatif
    .recupererPensionsActivesParBeneficiaires(
    Arrays.asList(idBeneficiaire),
    context.getIdentificationContext());
for (final Map.Entry<Long, List<PensionMediumView>> entry : mapPensionsBeneficiaire.entrySet()){
    for(PensionMediumView pension : enter.getValue()) {
        // I wasn't sure of how to get the pension id from your example
        // So just replace this with example getter with however you get your pension ID
        if(pension.typePensionId() == 21) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
            break; // This will stop the loop, 
            // if you want the loop to continue, don't use this
        }
    }
}
```